# Decorator pattern implementations - extends vs implements

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I create decorator pattern example:

interface:

```
public interface Printer {
  void print(String message);
}
```

implementation:

```
public class StringPrinter implements Printer {

  public void print(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
  }
}
```

and 2 decorators:

change string to upper case:

```
public class UpCasePrinter implements Printer {

  private Printer printer;

  public UpCasePrinter(Printer printer) {
    this.printer = printer;
  }

  public void print(String message) {
    printer.print(message.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

print reverse string:

```
public class InversePrinter implements Printer {

  private Printer printer;

  public InversePrinter(Printer printer) {
    this.printer = printer;
  }

  public void print(String message) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(message);
    printer.print(builder.reverse().toString());
  }
}
```

All work fine. But when reading examples on different sites I find different implementations. Each decarator `extends` from another. And I saw the realization of `BufferedInputStream`

```
BufferedInputStream extends FilterInputStream
FilterInputStream extends InputStream
public abstract class InputStream implements Closeable
```

I can not understand the following:

1. Is there a difference in how to create a decorator? as for me - the decorator `implements` the same interface as the original class or as in the examples - the decorator is `extends` from another decorator, etc. [link for extends realization](https://www.journaldev.com/1540/decorator-design-pattern-in-java-example)
2. may be in the example with the BufferedInputStream such a realization only because the abstract class was chosen at the start and not the interface?

**EDIT:**

[image]

in other words, I do not understand what is the use `CarDecorator`

`LuxerCar` and `SportsCar` can `implement Car` interface and `not extends` from `CarDecorator`. What is the benefit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BufferedInputStream` is implemented in exactly the same way as your `Car` example. It decorates an `InputStream` which, although it's an abstract class, still provides a contract, just as an interface would. An abstract class was chosen in this case because there are methods with default behaviour (`read` and `skip`) and, at the time the class was written, interfaces were not able to support this (they can now, but [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) 
 in interfaces were added much later).

Because an abstract class was used for the contract, `BufferedInputStream` extends `FilterInputStream`, just as `CarDecorator` implements `Car`. Both are just simple holders for a delegate. They contain a single `protected` field (an `InputStream` and a `Car`) and delegate all method calls to the field. The reason for this is because, if you have a large number of methods in your contract, delegating all of the methods in every decorator might result in a lot of code duplication. When your interface only has a single method, as yours does, then it provides very little benefit.

This is certainly not a necessary component of the decorator pattern; it's just a slightly different way of implementing it. Your implementation is still a 100% correct implementation of the decorator pattern.

Comment: A `BufferedInputStream` is also an example of the decorator pattern so I'm not sure why you say it is not.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Right again. I said that because it's not using a common interface, but you could definitely make the case that that's not a meaningful distinction. I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Well, it is using a common interface, except that it is defined in an abstract class (`InputStream`), not in a literal interface. But both are considered interfaces in the theoretical sense.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sure, but the whole point of the decorator pattern is to favour composition over inheritance, so I'd argue that using an abstract class hierarchy really isn't following the pattern (that's fine - of course, not everything has to follow a pattern). Following the pattern, `BufferedInputStream` should be *decorated by* `FilterInputStream` and should not extend it.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with you. The decorating happens like buffer(file input) or stream-to-reader(buffer(file input)), etc. The inheritance is used to share common implementation of the plumbing of a stream, if inheritance was used to alter behavior then you'd get something like a `BufferedFileInputStream` (and a `BufferedSocketInputStream`, etc. Sure, I'd guess that if this would be designed now, there might be differences in its design, but the choice for using inheritance for this is sound.